# Different Border Color for Button in UWP using template style

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I need different border colors for button in uwp.It need to be done in template as below,no style property can be applied.The below code excerpt applies a blue like borderbottom color.I need to apply a different color for the rest of borders.It is some customization like borderrightbrush,borderleftbrush instead of the general borderbrush which applies to the entire border

```
`<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />        
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3272B2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#155EA8" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2" />`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom template where you put a `Border` around the `ContentPresenter`:

```
<Button Content="Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3272B2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#155EA8" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="OuterBorderEdge" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderThickness="2,2,2,0" BorderBrush="Red">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                      CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">

                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

[image]

If you need different colours, you could for example use a `Grid`:

```
<Button Content="Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3272B2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="OuterBorderEdge" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="2" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="2" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="Yellow" />
                            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="Green" />
                            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="Red" />
                            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#155EA8" />
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                      CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">

                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

[image]